# Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache ---------- in asp mvc 5 when install idenitiy

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i need use asp mvc 5 identity . i create empty project in Visual Studio 2015 .

when i enter this for install identity :

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Pre
```

in my project show me this error :

[image]

i add this refrence `System.Net.Http` but still i have this probelm .

why show me this error ? how can i solve this ?

Comment: Is `System.Runtime` in your GAC? From PowerShell I see it in the GAC using this command: `&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /l system.runtime`

Comment: i entered show me this : 

`Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  system.runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Number of items = 1`